# Python threading override init

Tags: python, multithreading, class, inheritance, initialization

I am using threading.py and I have the following code:

```
import threading  
class MyClass(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self,par1,par2):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
       self.var1 = par1  
       self.var2 = par2  
    def run(self):
       #do stuff with var1 and var2 while conditions are met
... 
... 
... 
myClassVar = MyClass("something",0.0)
```

And I get the following error:

```
18:48:08    57  S E myClassVar = MyClass("something",0.0)  
18:48:08    58  S E File "C:\Python24\Lib\threading.py", line 378, in `__init__`  
18:48:08    59  S E assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"  
18:48:08    60  S E AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

I am kind of new using python, it is the first time I use threading...

What is the bug here?

Thank you,

Jonathan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to extend `Thread` to use threads. I usually use this pattern...

```
def worker(par1, par2):
    pass # do something

thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=("something", 0.0))
thread.start()
```

Comment: So all the conditions and actions are defined in worker? So worker would be _LIKE_ the run function?

Comment: Yep, it's like the run function.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a class and override thread as you have in your example, you just need to change the call to super to be correct. For example:

```
import threading  
class MyClass(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self,par1,par2):
       super(MyClass, self).__init__()
       self.var1 = par1  
       self.var2 = par2  
    def run(self):
       #do stuff with var1 and var2 while conditions are met
```

The call to init already gets self sent to it, so when you provide it again it sets another argument in the Thread class constructor and things get confused.